# How to count the Null values in if/else condition using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I suppose to create a condition that's counting the null value.If the null value counts up to 10 an email will be sent to the people for their to notify that the system didn't scan any barcode labels. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter=0;
 for(//your range like an array maybe)
 {
  if(your condition==null)
  counter++;
 }
 if(counter=10)
 {
   //do stuff
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how the code answers the question improves its long-term value. It also helps avoid having your answer down-voted or flagged as low quality. See [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @EricBrandt if possible,kindly edit the answer,it would help..thanks